# Flutter FormatException: Unexpected character

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-android

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 8242): Failed
E/flutter ( 8242): ^
E/flutter ( 8242):
E/flutter ( 8242): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1405:5)
E/flutter ( 8242): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1272:9)
E/flutter ( 8242): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:937:22)
E/flutter ( 8242): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
E/flutter ( 8242): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
```

The API is working better in Postman it is giving very good response in the form of JSON.But here in flutter it is giving error like this.

```
 static Future<GetPoliceCalculatedInsigniaMode?>
      fetchGetCalculatedInsigniaInfo(String idcard, String token) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {"idcard": idcard, "token": token};
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(
        PersonalInformationAPI.getCalculatedInsgniaInfoURL,
      ),
      body: data,
      headers: {
        "tanjai": "DefaInw(1.0.0)",
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      var jsonString = response.body;
      return GetPoliceCalculatedInsigniaMode.fromJson(
        jsonDecode(jsonString),
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: can you send us your code?

Comment: @YunusEmreÇelik yes pasted above sir.

Comment: @kingmort {
  "positiondate": "****-**-**",
  "position": "------------",
  "subdivision": "text in thai",
  "division": "text in thai",
  "bureau": "text in thai"
}

this is the response i am getting from VSCODE THUNDER

Comment: yes sir same output from post man sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244978/discussion-between-sai-mahesh-paruchuri-and-king-mort).